# passing model from view to controller using ajax call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor

I am making an application, in which it is required to create a lead when user enters the mobile number and tab out, the lead is created if entered mobile number is valid(with all other details on the form). But when i am passing model from view to controller the data i 'm getting null.

**View**

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "EmailQuote";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Template.cshtml";
    }
    @model Max.VirtualSalesManager.UI.ViewModels.LeadViewModel

    @{
     var data = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    }
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Common.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <h2>
       EmailQuote</h2>
    @using Acidaes.VirtualSalesManager.UI.Helpers
    @using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateEQuote", "Quote", FormMethod.Post,             new{id="frmEmailQuote" }))
    {

      @Html.MandatoryLabel("Name", false, new { style = "width: 50px; display: inline" })     @Html.FullName()
   @Html.MandatoryLabel("City", false, new { style = "width: 50px; display: inline" }) @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CommunicationAddress.City, new SelectList(ViewBag.CityList, "Key", "Value"), "select", new { id = "ddlCity" })
   @Html.MandatoryLabel("Mobile No.", false, new { style = "width: 100px; display: inline" }) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MobileNumber, new { style = "width: 100px", id = "txtmobilenumber", onBlur = "createLead('"+@data+"')" })
   @Html.MandatoryLabel("Email ID", false, new { style = "width: 80px; display: inline" }) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailId, new { style = "width: 100px" })
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LeadId)
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

**Js**

```
function createLead(data) {
var number = /^[0-9]+$/;
var mobileNumber = document.getElementById('txtmobilenumber').value;
if (mobileNumber.match(number) && mobileNumber.length == 10) {
    var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
    var Parameters = "{'data':'" + ("#frmEmailQuote").serialize() + "'}";
    Events.DoServerRequest('/MAXVSM/Quote/test', Parameters, GetLeadId);
}
}
```

> DoServerRequest Function

```
 DoServerRequest: function (url, data, funSuccess) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: funSuccess,
        error: function () {
            alert("Error in getting list");
        }
    });


Controller
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("test")]
    public JsonResult test(LeadViewModel data)
    {
        LeadViewModel t = new LeadViewModel();
        t.MobileNumber = data.MobileNumber;

        return Json(t);
    }
```

The data reaching fine from view to ajax function, but when the data is reaching to controller it is null.

Comment: Try changing this line so you don't have sub property: `var Parameters = ("#frmEmailQuote").serialize();`

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `contentType` from your ajax call:

```
DoServerRequest: function (url, data, funSuccess) {
    $.post({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: funSuccess,
        error: function () {
            alert("Error in getting list");
        }
    });
}
```

The server is not expecting JSON content but application/x-www-form-urlencoded which is the default value.

This means you should also use a normal Javascript object or string as data:

```
if (mobileNumber.match(number) && mobileNumber.length == 10) {
    Events.DoServerRequest('/MAXVSM/Quote/test', $("#frmEmailQuote").serialize(), GetLeadId);
}
```

Comment: why you have passed mobileNumber as an parameter. ("#frmEmailQuote").serialize() will contain all the parameters in the form??

Comment: You are right. I have updated the answer. You should be able to pass the serialized string directly.